# Can someone Improve on this Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, lamp

```
SELECT Services.Type, Description
    , CASE
       WHEN id = $user_id THEN 'YES'
       ELSE 'NO'
    END AS Checked
    , Details
from Services
LEFT JOIN SellerServices ON SellerServices.Type = Services.Type    
WHERE `id` =$user_id
OR
 Services.Type NOT IN
  (
    SELECT  SellerServices.Type
    FROM     SellerServices
    where id =$user_id
  )
```

To Explain the Tables Involved, SellerServices is a table that describes which services a particular seller offers.

Services describes all the services.

If I was not joining these tables, a simple "select * from Services where 1" would nearly accomplish the goal of which rows to return, but as it is I have only found a subquery capable of accomplishing the task:

The second clause, where the Services.Type not in Subquery finds one each of the Services where the $user_id doesn't match, or it is null.  These are the services the seller does not offer.

The first clause finds the services he offers.  The case statement gives output in a format I like.

It works, but is there a way to improve it?

Comment: I would check out this site... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am looking at this... I haven't had a lot of coffee yet.  What is the query actually returning?  You want a list of all services, and Y/N if that `$user_id` is associated with those services?

Comment: YOu need to specify which database backend you are using. Performance tuning is very much database specific.  IN SQL server I would suggest using Union All (or UNion if teh datasets are nto mutually exclusive) instead of OR  and where NOT exists instead of not in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list services along with a "yes" or "no" flag indicating whether it is offered, you can do something like this:

```
select s.type, s.description,
       (case when exists (select 1 from SellerServices ss where ss.Type = s.Type and ss.id = $user_id)
             then 'YES'
             else 'NO'
        end) as Checked,
       s.details
from services s;
```

Your question doesn't specify where `details` comes from, so I'm guessing from `services`.

You can also write this as a `left outer join`, assuming that there are no duplicates in the `SellerServices` table:

```
select s.type, s.description,
       (case when ss.Type is not null
             then 'YES'
             else 'NO'
        end) as Checked,
       ss.details
from Services s left join
     SellerServices ss
     on ss.Type = s.Type and ss.id = $user_id;
```

This can handle `details` coming from either table.

Comment: The latter solution works, and it is less convoluted than what I had.  Thank you.  (Assuming there are no duplicates... There won't be duplicates as long as $user_id is fixed) there could be many duplicates if not.